# MySQL Query optimization in PHP

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have three tables, all of them can have possibly millions of rows. I have an actions table and a reactions table, that holds reactions related to actions. Then there is a emotes table linked to reactions. What I would like to do with this particular query, is finding the most clicked emote for a certain action. The difficulty for me is that the query includes three tables instead of only two.

Table actions (postings):

```
PKY id
...
```

Table reactions (comments, emotes etc.):

```
PKY id
INT action_id (related to actions table)
...
```

Table emotes:

```
PKY id
INT react_id (related to reactions table)
INT emote_id (related to a hardcoded list of available emotes)
...
```

The SQL query I came up with basically seems to work, but it takes 12 seconds if the tables contain millions rows. The SQL query looks like this:

```
select emote_id, count(*) as cnt from emotes
where react_id in (
   select id from reactions where action_id=2942715
)
group by emote_id order by cnt desc limit 1
```

MySQL explain says the following:

```
id  select_type         table       type            possible_keys       key         key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY             emotes      index           NULL                react_id_2  21          NULL    4358594 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  reactions   unique_subquery PRIMARY,action_id   PRIMARY     8           func    1       Using where
```

...I am grateful for any tips for improving on the query. Note that I will NOT call this query every time a list of actions is being built, but only when emotes are being added. Therefore it's no problem if the query takes maybe 0.5 seconds to finish. But 12 is too long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this

```
SELECT
    emote_id,
    count(*) as cnt
FROM emotes a
INNER JOIN reactions r
    ON r.id = a.react_id
WHERE action_id = 2942715
GROUP BY emote_id
ORDER BY cnt DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Three rows touched, 0.0002 seconds. This helps me a lot, thanks!

Comment: Or in native tongue: Merci ;)